# How do you prevent the "init" function to be called after a chaincode has been instantiated in a Hyperledger Fabric NodeJS smart contract?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I am writing a simple NodeJS smart contract.  It has an `init` method that will be called when the chaincode is instantiated:

```
'use strict';
const { Contract } = require('fabric-contract-api');
const shim = require('fabric-shim');

class BlueCoinContract extends Contract {
  async init(ctx){
    console.info('============= START : Init =============');
    :
    :
    console.info('============= END : Init =============');
  }

  :
  :
}
```

To instantiate the chaincode, I use the following command:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n blue-coin -l "$CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE" -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"
```

The `Args` property needs to specify the name of the method (i.e., which is `init`) so that it will be called during instantiation.

I initially thought that the `init` method can be called only during instantiation since the `init` method may contain code that will initialize some values in the world state (e.g., set values to zero).

However, I realized that the same `init` method can be called beyond initialization by calling the invoke command:

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n blue-coin -c '{"function":"init","Args":[]}'
```

If a user can execute the `init` command beyond initialization, there is a risk that the values in the world state will be reinitialized to its initial value.

Is there a way to prevent this?  I am thinking of saving a `flag` in the world state once the `init` method is called.  In this way, I can have the `init` method check the `flag` first and throw an error if it detected that it already exist (i.e., because it was already called before).

Is there a more acceptable/appropriate solution than the one I described?

Answer (score 2):

you would get **Invalid Smart Contract function name** if you try to initialize chaincode again with invoke.

Bellow is an explanation why

- Once initialized the chaincode can be again initialized only when we
  are upgrading the chaincode.
- This is how the chaincode stub interface is designed,
   The **chaincodestubinterface** exposes functions init and invoke for   interaction with the chaincode run time.
- An instance of the stub interface is received by the init and
  invoke function as argument.
- now based on stub  Object received in args of init/invoke we build
  functions in the chaincode eg createCar,deleteCar.

Comment: Hi @Risabh.  In the peer instantiate and peer invoke command in my example, both commands are successful.  I was thinking that the peer instantiate command will work, while peer invoke will throw an error since it invoked the same function "init", however it still returned "Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200".

Comment: btw, I am using the "fabric-contract-api" NodeJS API.  There are no required "Init" and "Invoke" methods.  I can define a method called "myFunc" and indicate this as the function to call in the instantiate and it will still work.

Comment: 1)Fabric-contract-api uses fabric-shim under the hood.Its just a high level api to simplify contract development.2)yes it is because your self defined init function is using the invoke method to interact with chaincode runtime this link would explain it, https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-node/tree/release-1.4/fabric-contract-api#usage The first line itself says the functions defined are invokable functions only and not init.3)While the init function used with command peer chaincode instantiate is using the Init method to interact with the chaincode runtime.

Comment: just try to use peer chaincode instantiate command again and you would see and error.but if you use invoke in wont.this says that you have been invoking the chaincode with your init function and not initializing it.

Comment: Thanks @Risabh.  I looked at the link you shared.  It has two sets of code: (A) one that uses fabric-contract-api (B) one that uses fabric-shim.   Approach B is similar to the typical chaincode used in previous version of Hyperledger Fabric and clearly differentiates the Init and Invoke functions.  Does this mean Approach B is more reliable (i.e., you cannot trigger the Init function beyond the instantiate phase)?

Comment: B is a low level api,which means you get a fine grain control over the contract.while A is high level api which means it gets your generic work done without you knowing whats going inside.

Comment: Yes you cannot trigger init beyond the instantiation phase.

Comment: Thanks @Risabh.  Approach A would be simpler to read and maintain.  However B is more reliable. I thought originally that in A, the constructor serves as the Init function (i.e., since it is called only once), but it has no access to ctx nor have arguments.

Comment: You could use client identity library to conrtol the access on who can invoke your init function.hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Using some `flag` data in the world state is a good solution so that you initial setup of the world state does not get re-run.

You could also use the [ClientIdentity class](https://fabric-shim.github.io/master/fabric-shim.ClientIdentity.html) within your init function to check the Identity of the invoker of the function, or even check an attribute of the ID so that only an Administrator or Operator could run the init function. (Attribute based access control.)

The ClientIdentity object is automatically included in the contract context when using the fabric-contract-api so you don't need to explicitly 'require' it.

Comment: Does this mean if use the fabric-rest-api in NodeJS, the use of flag is the only approach to ensure that my init function will not get re-run?  I was hoping that the constructor serves as the init function since it can only be called once, but it has no access to ctx and arguments.

Comment: as mentioned by R Thatcher, you need to check the world state. A simple `ctx.stub.getState` check inside the `init` transaction function (in your 1.4.x code sample above), whether a flag, or forensic footprint as proof it was run, is sufficient (The key is indexed so it will not be 'costly'). If called by an API, it can be resolved to a true or false.